# Error declaring "using namespace" with a nested namespace ("namespace xxx::yyy not allowed in using-declaration")

Tags: c++, namespaces

When I write C++ code, I try to use a `using <X>` to keep from polluting too much. In Crypto++, it gives me problem in one case. The case is the ASN1 namespace within the CryptoPP namespace (it only shows up in one place).

Here's the declaration in Crypto++: http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/oids_8h_source.html.

I can use, for example, `secp256r1` curve with:

```
CryptoPP::ASN1::secp256r1();
```

However, I have not figured out a way to declare it with using. When I try:

```
#include <cryptopp/asn.h>
#include <cryptopp/oids.h>
using CryptoPP::ASN1;
```

It eventually leads to `error: namespace ‘CryptoPP::ASN1’ not allowed in using-declaration`, and then `error: ‘ASN1’ has not been declared` at the following (I tried them both):

```
ECIES<ECP>::Decryptor d1(prng, secp256r1());
ECIES<ECP>::Decryptor d2(prng, ASN1::secp256r1());
```

How does one use a `using` statement when there is more than one namespace?

---

```
$ g++ -version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2
```

Comment: `using namespace CryptoPP::ASN1;`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just say:

```
using namespace CryptoPP::ASN1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Charles. That results in `error: ‘ASN1’ has not been declared` at `ASN1::secp256r1()`.

Comment: Call `secp256r1()` directly without the namespace qualifier

Answer (score 14):

The other answers recomend `using namespace CryptoPP::ASN1;` but that's not what you wanted (presumably) as it imports *all* the contents of the `ASN1` namespace into your scope.

My guess is you wanted to do this:

```
namespace ASN1 = CryptoPP::ASN1;
```

This will allow you to use for example `ASN1::secp256r1()` in your scope.

Answer (score 4):

ASN1 is a namespace.  Try:

```
using namespace CryptoPP::ASN1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Silpertan. That results in `error: ‘ASN1’ has not been declared` at `ASN1::secp256r1()`.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
using CryptoPP::ASN1::secp256r1;
```

...then calling `secp256r` without qualification. That avoids using the namespace, which some frown on.